# Allow user to add notes to an OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers-2

I am looking for any ideas here. I want a user to be able to interact with a map. I know I can use HTML5 canvas to allow the user to draw over a map. But what about if I want something simpler? For instance, the user can click on the map, which will add a textbox and pinpoint - the user can then write notes for any locations they place this point. Is there a library which will allow me to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Although HTML 5 is fine, features can also be drawn on the map by the user using HTML 4, as can be seen in this old OpenLayers example: "OpenLayers Draw Feature Example" (http://goo.gl/k3Dhu).

Comment: could you please point to your example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you search more simple thing with openlayers, you can allow user to add point with `label` which `opacity` have to be 0. So you can see only text which is inherited from your point.

if you want any code, i can write something for you.

i hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can figure it out looking at an example. This should work fine.